# WAS 8.5 Admin console - Give only access to Deployment

Tags: websphere, ibm-was

We have a shared WAS 8.5 server and we want to give only deployment access to other teams. we do not want them to change any other server configurations/options. Can we do this using WAS 8.5 Admin console?

Basically we want to create a role based access and when users log in to admin console with that role they should have access to only deployment option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly deployer role, the other answer is incorrect. Deployer cannot change any server configuration options (except managing application), and cannot start/stop servers.

> Deployer role
>
> A user that is granted a deployer role can complete all of the
>   configuration and runtime operations on an application. A deployer
>   role can be subsets of both configurator and operator roles. However,
>   a user granted a **deployer role cannot configure or operate any other
>   resources, such as a server, node**.

In addition, if you have many servers, you can scope that role via `Security > Administrative authorization groups` to the selected server/cluster. In that case that user will be able to only deploy apps to that server/cluster.

For detailed description see - [Administrative roles - Deployer role](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rsec_adminroles.html#rsecadminroles__deployerrole)